# Highlight target cell with a color linked with a HYPERLINK

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have implemented a functionality where there are dynamic hyperlinks across several rows. These HYPERLINKS point to different cells across different worksheets within the same workbook. When I click on any of the HYPERLINKS, I can navigate to that target cell.

Now, by default, that cell is highlighted by a thick black border. Is there any way I could make that cell appear with a specific color whenever it gets highlighted after the HYPERLINK gets clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Great problem! We can use worksheet events to handle this. The event that I feel is appropriate to use is the *follow hyperlink* event. Not sure how to set this up via python to be honest. But was fun working on it anyways! Goodluck.

Code is as follows:

The event itself, in Sheet that contains your hyperlink:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    AlterHyperLinkedRanged.Main Target
End Sub
```

**Regular Module Named *AlterHyperLinkedRanged***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main(Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim ParsedSubAddress As ParsedSubAddress
    Set ParsedSubAddress = New ParsedSubAddress

    ParsedSubAddress.Parse Target.Subaddress

    Dim HyperLinkedRange As Range
    Set HyperLinkedRange = ParsedSubAddress.Worksheet.Range(ParsedSubAddress.Address)

    HyperLinkedRange.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End Sub
```

And the class we created to store the data given to use by target.subaddress, AKA the range whose border we are looking to change. I created a new object to handle parse and store this data. I am doing this on the fly, feel free to improve! This code will go inside a class module.

**Class Named *ParsedSubAddress*:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Attrib
    Address As String
    WS As Worksheet
End Type

Private this As Attrib

Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = this.Address
End Property

Private Property Let Address(value As String)
    this.Address = value
End Property

Public Property Get Worksheet() As Worksheet
    Set Worksheet = this.WS
End Property

Private Property Let Worksheet(value As Worksheet)
    this.WS = value
End Property

Function Parse(ByVal Subaddress As String)
    If Not (InStr(Subaddress, "!") > 0) Then
        this.Address = Subaddress
        Set this.WS = ActiveSheet
    Else
        this.Address = Mid(Subaddress, InStr(Subaddress, "!") + 1, Len(Subaddress))
        Set this.WS = Sheets(Mid(Subaddress, 1, InStr(Subaddress, "!") - 1))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts! I'll give this a try with respect to my scenario. Thanks!