# How to highlight the hyperlinked cell in the openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to highlight the cell which is hyperlinked, that means when you click the cell is sheet1 and it hyperlinks to sheet2 the sheet2 cell must highlight.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the content below in the cell, then you can click hyperlink "sheet2" and navigate to sheet2 A3 cell

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A3", "sheet2")
```

Comment: ws['G6'] = "=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A3", "sheet2")"

Comment: I want to highlight the cell with a color(yellow)

Comment: I mean you click the hyperlink cell in sheet1 , it takes you to second sheet i.e. sheet2 and highlight the cell in sheet2.

Comment: I don't think openpyxl can help you but you can use VBA to do that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975110/highlight-target-cell-with-a-color-linked-with-a-hyperlink

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/highlight-a-cell-when-using-hyperlink/ed416004-cc9d-43bf-a670-890d6ca2bb2e

Comment: the only possible way, you can use xlsxwriter to add VBA code to the excel 
https://pbpython.com/advanced-excel-workbooks.html